# Accessing non-existent property of a hashtable behaves differently in and out of the module

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

In a PowerShell script or a simple one-file psm1 module accessing a non-existent property of a hashtable returns $null

```
$hashtable = @{}
$hashtable.NonExistentKey -eq $null # returns true
```

But when this code is a part of a proper module with a psd1 manifest the same code throws an exception

> The property 'NonExistentKey' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.

Maybe someone knows what's the reason for this behavior and if it can be changed?

UPD: I know that **ContainsKey** is the proper way, but it concerns executing legacy code and different behavior in general.

UPD2: **Set-StrictMode** was indeed the case. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: `Set-StrictMode`. The module likely has this active (and that's good practice). Use `.ContainsKey` to check if there's a key before accessing it.

Comment: You shouldn't be checking the existence of a key like that anyway. Hashtables have a method `ContainsKey()` for this exact purpose.

Comment: If it's "legacy code", then just turn strict mode off again: `Set-StrictMode -Off`. Its effects are scoped, so you can selectively apply it where necessary. There's quite a few ways to tweak strict mode and set a default preference, so within a module it's never a good idea to rely on any particular mode being in effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by @Jeroen Mostert above, strict mode might be active.

PowerShell session with active strict mode:

```
> Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0
> $d = @{}
> $d.SomeNotExistingKey
The property 'SomeNotExistingKey' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ $d.SomeNotExistingKey
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

PowerShell session WITHOUT active strict mode:

```
> $d = @{}                    
> $d.SomeNotExistingKey
```

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-5.1):

> ... When strict mode is on, Windows PowerShell generates a terminating error when the content of an expression, script, or script block violates basic best-practice coding rules.

Hope that helps